# DropDownList action on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist that already works in my view, except you have to press the submit button.  Is there a way to have it work on the click event instead of the using the Submit button.  I've found several people asking the same question, but using different syntax for the dropdownlist.  Do I need to completely change my syntax or is there something I can add to make it work with what I have?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>

        <legend>Select a State</legend>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("listStates", "Select a State")
    </div>
    <p>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </p>

</fieldset>

}
```

Thanks for the link.  Here's what I used:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var query = _db.States.Select(c => new { c.Id, c.Name });
        ViewData["listStates"]  = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Name");

        return View();

    }
```

Razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "FloorPLan", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>

        <legend>Select a State</legend>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Id", (SelectList) ViewData["listStates"], "Select a State", new{
      onchange = "document.getElementById('TheForm').submit();"
   })
    </div>


</fieldset>
```

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists

Comment: can do this with some js. jquery can make this simple

Comment: I am not a big fan of adding javascript inline with my html.  It would be much cleaner/maintainable if you keep the two separated.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind using jquery, then try the following

```
$('#Id).on('change', function(){
    $('#TheForm').submit();
});
```